# Which case to use with posthinc?

Tags: grammar-choice, adverb, time, case

L&S mentions that [*abhinc*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=abhinc&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) can be used with either accusative or ablative.
But no use guidance is given for [*posthinc*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=posthinc&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
Can I use both accusative and ablative to express the length of time, or only one?
The Vergilius quotes given in L&S do not express any period of time, but I would like to know how to say things like "I will go to Rome four days from now".
Is it even possible to express the period of time with *posthinc*, or should I be using some other word?
I prefer to use *posthinc* if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a first note, I have been unable to find a classical work where *posthinc* is treated as one word. The two Vergil citations in the L&S entry you mentioned actually have *post hinc*:

> **post hinc** digressus iubeo frondentia capris
>   arbuta sufficere et fluuios praebere recentis, (V. *G* 3:300-301)

and

> **post hinc** ad nauis graditur sociosque reuisit. (V. *A* 8:546)

These really are not terribly good examples of a new grammatical form. In fact, two authorities contest this:

1. Servius Honoratus, in his commentary to 8:546, sees it as a **pleonasm**. Evidently he was struck by the form enough that he even recalls the passage from the *Georgics* when considering the one from the *Aeneid.*

   > *post hinc ad naves graditvr:* **unum vacat, aut 'post', aut 'hinc'**, ut "post hinc digrediens iubeo frondentia capris arbuta": tale est et illud "primus ibi ante omnes".
2. August Engelbrecht, in his [*Untersuchungen über die sprache des Claudianus Mamertus*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AO5GAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA523&lpg=PA523), pg. 102-103, sees them as two adverbs with separate functions:

   > Das Lexikon von Forcellini bringt auch noch in seiner neuen Ausgabe zwar zwei Stellen für *posthinc* bei, die jedoch beide unbrauchbar sind.... Augenscheinlich ist an beiden Stellen *hinc* nicht mit *post* sondern mit *graditur (digressus)* zu verbinden ebenso ist Sid carm VII 435.

   My translation:

   > Indeed, Forcellini's lexicon also furnishes in its new edition two locations for *posthinc*. However, neither is applicable. Evidently, in both locations ***hinc* should not be construed with *post* but rather with *graditur/digressus***, just as in Sidonius, *Carmina 7:435*.

However, Engelbrecht goes on to cite a passage from Servius (caveat: although I looked where he said it was, I could not find the relevant quote) that may lend credence to the one word/form theory:

> Uebrigens kann die Bemerkung des Servius zur letzteren Stelle aus Vergil, "Sunt qui posthinc unica uoce scribunt, sed perperam," als Beweis dienen dass zu des Grammatikers Zeiten *posthinc = postea* in Gebrauch gewesen sein muss.

Translation:

> Incidentally, Servius's remark on this last citation from Vergil, "There are some who write *posthinc* as one word, but this is incorrect," can serve as evidence that *posthinc = postea* must have been in use at the time the grammatician was writing.

There are examples where the *hinc* cannot be linked with another verb in the sentence. Here is one example from Marcus Manilius, *Astronomica*:

> Fortunae sors prima data est....
>   ...
>   **post hinc** militiae locus est, qua quidquid in armis
>   quodque peregrinas inter versantibus urbes
>   accidere assuevit titulo comprenditur uno. (3: 96-104)

Here, the only possible rendering of *post hinc* is a single logical "afterwards," like *postea.* I think that Honoratus's comment about this being pleonastic is probably applicable here. It is telling that all these examples (as well as another I found from Lucretius) occur in verse, where metrical constraints allow more creative constructions.

---

As for your practical question about translating, "I will go to Rome four days from now," I think in light of the above that *posthinc* together would not be appropriate. I recommend either the obvious *post (prep)* + accusative or *post (adv)* + ablative:

> Romam post tres dies (tribus post diebus) ibo.

Or, if you would like to emphasize the "from now" part, you could certainly use *hinc*, in the model of Varro, *De Lingua Latina*, 5:144,

> hinc post triginta annos oppidum alterum conditur, Alba.

For example:

> Hinc post tres dies Romam ibo.

Of course it would be very difficult to find a context where *hinc* couldn't also be taken as a spatial adverb.